# How do I use @Url.Content() in non-MVC Razor webpage?

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-2

Since I'm using Web Application having NuGet Package's Microsoft.AspNet.Razor installed.

In WebForm pages (*.aspx), I can use ResolveUrl() but in Razor pages (*.cshtml), I get this error -->

```
"x:\Source\Foo.Dealer\Foo.Dealer.WebApp.Mobile\Member\DmsDashboard.cshtml(103): error CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context"
```

Source-Code here..

```
@section HeadJavascriptLibraryFile
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/webpages/setting-dmsdashboard.js")"></script>
}
```

and

```
<img src="@(Url.Content("~/images/miscellaneous/reportandpiechart2.png"))" alt="" />
```

Source Code as requested...

```
//LayoutMembmerGeneral.cshtml
@using Foo.Dealer.WebApp.Mobile.Infrastructure;
@{
    if (LoginManagementTools.DealerUserLoginValidation_BrowsingPage(HttpContext.Current.Request, HttpContext.Current.Response, HttpContext.Current.Session) == false) { }
}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>@Page.Title</title>
  @RenderSection("HeadJavascriptLibraryFile", false)
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>

//DmsDashboard.cshtml...
@using Foo.Dealer.WebApp.Mobile.Infrastructure
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@{
    Page.Title = "A New Dawn In Auto Pricing";
    Layout = "LayoutMemberGeneral.cshtml";
}
@section HeadJavascriptLibraryFile
{
}

<div id="WebLayout1">
    <img src="@Url.Content("images/miscellaneous/reportandpiechart2.png")" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Also what version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: Did intellisense kick in when you added `@using System.Web.Mvc`? (no semi colon by the way)

Comment: Yes it does kicked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL helper doesn't seem to exist in ASP.Net Web Pages (which is essentially what you are attempting to do), but you can simply use the following code to achieve the same effect:

`<img src="~/images/miscellaneous/reportandpiechart2.png" alt="" />`

The tilde (~) references the application root and is transformed when the page is compiled and sent to the client.

Comment: The thing is why keep renaming the filepath if moving the file around to different path.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the above essentially does the same thing as @Url.Content(...), so you would have the same issue anyway.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Razor views when used outside the context of MVC falls under the domain of ASP.Net Web Pages, which is the ability to use .cshtml pages directly.  I'm not disputing the fact that they are using Razor views, it just has nothing to do with MVC so you have to be aware what is available and what isn't.

Comment: Right but the question is what's the equivalent of Url.Content this way in ASP.Net Web Pages?

Comment: @fletchsod my example is the equivalent :)

Comment: Look like I'll have to wait until Microsoft start adding support for it, to newer Microsoft.AspNet.Razor version down the road or worse, Microsoft never will add the support for it.

Comment: You can always grab the source code for it from GitHub and implement it yourself :) https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/a55dcae32f0c5e49d11b804718a8042f8e503b9c/src/System.Web.Http/Routing/UrlHelper.cs

Comment: You were correct. I should read the title of the question as well as the content next time :)

Answer (score 1):

The tilde (~) is not transformed as part of any `data-` attributes and likely, other places also, though I haven't researched extensively.

If you happen to need this information in a place where the automatic transofmration isn't working, you can use the tilde equivalent, `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath`.

In most Razor views, you should be able to shorten it to the following:

```
@Request.ApplicationPath
```

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx

Another alternative in some situations is to use the `VirtualPathUtility` such as:

```
@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")
```