# ASP.NET Web Site Razor v3: Html string containing img tag and set to variable not loading image

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

After trying, browsing, testing for hours I still don't get it. Here is the problem:

I've started the project with the ASP.NET Web Site Razor v3 template in Visual Studio Community 2013. Why the heck this code causes the latest (desktop) browsers **NOT** to load the images. As you see, the HTML string is set to the variable and then I try to output it as HTML code:
1st case code:

```
@{ var q = "<img src=\"~/Images/Arrow-Back-iconL.png\" alt=\"galerija puščica levo\" id=\"puscicaL_0\" class=\"puscica puscical\" style=\"opacity:1\" />";
 }
 @Html.Raw(q)
 @(new HtmlString(q))
```

But this code of course enables images to load:
2nd case code:

```
<img src="~/Images/Arrow-Back-iconL.png" alt="galerija puščica levo" id="puscicaL_0" class="puscica puscical" style="opacity:1" />
```

**EDIT:**
Of course, yesterday evening I forgot to present the rendered code. The first(Razor) case renders:

```
<img class="puscica puscical" id="puscicaL_0" style="opacity: 1;" alt="galerija puščica levo" src="~/Images/Arrow-Back-iconL.png">
```

The second case gives:

```
<img class="puscica puscical" id="puscicaL_0" style="opacity: 1;" alt="galerija puščica levo" src="/Images/Arrow-Back-iconL.png">
```

**SOLUTION**
The tilde(~) operator for virtual path, used in a HTML string, which is the argument of `HtmlString` constructor, must be resolved using the `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` class&properties. In Razor code the shortcut `@Request.ApplicationPath` can be applied. More about it at [How do I use @Url.Content() in non-MVC Razor webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207591/how-do-i-use-url-content-in-non-mvc-razor-webpage)

Example:

> ```
> @{
>      var urlq = @Request.ApplicationPath + "Images/Arrow-Back-iconL.png";
>      var q = "<img src=\""+urlq+"\" alt=\"galerija puščica levo\" id=\"puscicaL_0\" class=\"puscica puscical\" style=\"opacity:1\" />";
> }
> @(new HtmlString(q))
> ```

Comment: please see the rendered source of your web page and paste here if possible

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because of the `~` in the URL. That is used to indicate application root, but needs to be resolved before before sent to the browser. If possible you should resolve it before inserting it into the `q` variable like this:

```
@{
  var qUrl = Url.Content("~/Images/Arrow-Back-iconL.png");
  var q = string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"galerija puščica levo\" id=\"puscicaL_0\" class=\"puscica puscical\" style=\"opacity:1\" />", qUrl);
}

@Html.Raw(q)
@(new HtmlString(q))
```

Comment: @Chrisopher Jennings, your answer was the step to the solution, but the `Url.Content` is not supported in ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v3) / Web Pages. Follow the link which I appended into the question, under the Solution section.